# Flutter bottom sheet partially appear

Tags: flutter, dart

I just migrate `flutter 3.7.2 to 3.12.0` and `auto_route: 5.0.4 to 7.4.0`. Does this have an impact on the bottom sheet ? how to fix the bottom sheet that appears partially ?

Bottom sheet snippet:

```dart
await showModalBottomSheet<void>(
  context: context,
  isScrollControlled: true,
  useSafeArea: true,
  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
  builder: (context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      height: 200,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    );
  }
);
```

Wondering why the bottom sheet not fully display even `useSafeArea: true`. The scaffold body also wrapped by `SafeArea`.

[image]

thankyou

Comment: Isn't it because you have made it scroll controlled and then set the child height to 200? So the content is more than 200px so you need to scroll to show the rest.

Comment: I don't realize that. but set `isScrollControlled: false` doesn't make any changes.

Comment: I tried your code in the new app. Everything seems fine. It looks like some other part of the code in your app is causing it.

Comment: @Mearaj suspect auto_route is causing this, because everything was perfect before upgrading the plugin

Comment: I have no idea about auto_route. If you provide more or relevant section of the code I may be able to figure it out. Also you can try using SafeArea widget to see if it helps.
Currently in your app, it seems like flutter is unaware that there's bottom bar, hence it's overlapping with it. Also you can try playing around with different options provided by showModalBottomSheet function.

Comment: Previously `useSafeArea` is enough to avoid intrusions. I just wrapped widget using `SafeArea` and worked. Lookslike there's a bug on `useSafeArea`. Thanks @Mearaj.

Comment: Np. Thanks to you too @omega_mi :)

Comment: I have added this resolution as answer, in case if anyone comes across similar situation.
If it's ok with you, can please mark my answer as answered.?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give additional `SafeArea` to showModalBottomSheet builder is not the best answer for me. This solution is not answer i can accept, because i developed both Android and iOS.

```dart
await showModalBottomSheet<void>(
  ...
  builder: (context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: YourWidget(),
    );
  }
);
```

Resolved on Android, but not iOS (as in the screenshot below).
[image]

Instead you must set to `useSafeArea: false`. And set your bottom padding that obtain from bottom viewPadding.

[viewPadding](https://medium.com/flutter-community/what-are-mediaquerys-padding-viewpadding-and-viewinsets-37ae11bc3bc2) define portions of the screen that are partially obscured by the System UI or some physical features, like a camera notch, cut-out, Dynamic Island, and what not. This is an inner padding of your available Flutter view that you should use to display content that should accept gestures and not be obstructed by anything.

```dart
await showModalBottomSheet<void>(
  ...
  useSafeArea: false,
  builder: (context) {
    return SafeArea(
      bottom: false, // disable bottom safe area
      child: Container(
         color: Colors.white,
         padding: EdgeInsets.only(
            bottom: MediaQuery.viewPaddingOf(context).bottom, // set bottom padding
         ),
         child: YourWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
);
```

according to expectations, I got what I wanted!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using [SafeArea](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SafeArea-class.html) resolves this issue.